# Best way of AEM 6.1 inter-component communication

Tags: content-management-system, aem

There are various ways to get data from one component and populate to another component. Via a SlingServlet etc.

However which is the best way which has less overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the relative path of one needed resource based on your current one, you can simply use the ResourceResolver to obtain the resource you need and get it's ValueMap to get whatever property you need from it:

```
Resource targetResource= resourceResolver.get('../relative/path');
ValueMap props= targetResource.getValueMap();
String name= props.get("jcr:title",String.class);
```

If you are using Sling models this can be particularly simple since you can inject resources directly as ValueMap, [see this](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#injector-specific-annotations-since-sling-models-impl-106)

If you don't know the path to your resource, you could either look for it with a query or use Javascript to do it in the front end.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Sightly Templates](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/block-statements.html#template%20&%20call) concept to pass arguments from one component to another component.

Another solution is: Component 1 to set values in request object and Component 2 read values from request and delete value from request.

Comment: can we use angular for this one ?